# TeX should be supported on GameDev, like on Math.SE, Physics, et. al

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [math markdown on this site](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351/math-markdown-on-this-site)

I was editing "[Detect mouse click on a bezier curve's neighborhood](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/33588/detect-mouse-click-on-a-bezier-curves-neighborhood#33588)" and was surprised to find that GameDev lacks TeX support.

Having TeX support would hugely improve readability of some quality answers such as,

- [Adding air drag to a golf ball trajectory equation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/11121/17107)
- [How to achieve uniform speed of movement on a bezier curve?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/27138/17107)

Although the majority of questions and answers present equations in code, it's useful to be able to discuss equations in math. Mathematical equations may have better documentation, are code agnostic and are probably how people studied the concepts in school.

I would love to be able to see this work,

$$
\Gamma(z) = \int_0^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt\,.
$$

Comment: Waiting for somebody to point out that we *do* have TeX support, but it's obscured in the FAQ and uses different tags from all the other sites.